# Virtual scroll shows white spaces on mobile devices with fast kinetic scrolling

Tags: angular, infinite-scroll, angular-cdk

I have developed a virtual scroll strategy that is inspired from Angular cdk virtual scroll. It works pretty well on desktop but the problem arises on mobile. Mobile has kinetic scroll implemented by default as the scroll behavior and that can be highly accelerated with hundreds of rows scrolling per second. With such a velocity of scroll I could see blank spaces at the bottom half of the scroll container. It fills up pretty quickly but the experience becomes a little glitchy. Even with Angular cdk scroll I could experience the same.

The main problem I see here is - when a container is scrolled either with scrollbar or finger swipe the container is actually scrolled and then the scroll event handler is invoked. It means the container is already scrolled even before your code gets chance to handle and throttle it down.
Is there really a way to throttle the velocity so that it can handled more smoothly.

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: Actually white space is expected because kinetic scroll can be so fast that render time would be more than scroll time. One solution is to implement the kinetic scroll manually that will allow you will control the acceleration. This page - https://dzone.com/articles/javascript-kinetic-scrolling has some info on implementing a custom kinetic scrolling scheme. Another solution is to use a pre generated ghost svg that would go in the background of the main container (background image with repeat), so even though main content would appear a little late, but ghost instead of white bg would appear.